# what APIs are available to connect to IBM websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a requirement, where I need to use IBM websphere message queue pub sub functionality.
Basically I have to write the subscriber part.
I need to know what all programming languages I can use to write the API other than java.
Can I write it using perl/shell/python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [PyMQI](https://pythonhosted.org/pymqi/) available for Python lovers. But note this offering is **NOT** from IBM.

Answer (score 1):

Use MQ Client API. It does include samples for C++ like this one:

```
int main ( int argc, char * * argv ) {
  ImqQueueManager mgr;             // Queue manager
  ImqQueue queue;                  // Queue
  ImqMessage msg;                  // Data message
  ImqGetMessageOptions gmo;        // Get message options
  char buffer[ 101 ];              // Message buffer
  ImqChannel * pchannel = 0 ;      // Channel definition

  printf( "Sample IMQSGET start\n" );
  if ( argc < 2 ) {
    printf( "Required parameter missing - queue name\n" );
    exit( 99 );
  }

  // Create object descriptor for subject queue
  queue.setName( argv[ 1 ] );
  if ( argc > 2 ) {
    mgr.setName( argv[ 2 ] );
  }

  // Define a channel for client communication.
  if ( argc > 3 ) {
    ImqString strParse( argv[ 3 ] );
    ImqString strToken ;

    pchannel = new ImqChannel ;
    pchannel -> setHeartBeatInterval( 1 );

    // Break down the channel definition,
    // which is of the form "channel-name/transport-type/connection-name".
    if ( strParse.cutOut( strToken, '/' ) ) {
      pchannel -> setChannelName( strToken );

      if ( strParse.cutOut( strToken, '/' ) ) {

        // Interpret the transport type.
        if ( strToken.upperCase( ) == (ImqString)"LU62" ) {
          pchannel -> setTransportType( MQXPT_LU62 );
        }
        if ( strToken.upperCase( ) == (ImqString)"NETBIOS" ) {
          pchannel -> setTransportType( MQXPT_NETBIOS );
        }
        if ( strToken.upperCase( ) == (ImqString)"SPX" ) {
          pchannel -> setTransportType( MQXPT_SPX );
        }
        if ( strToken.upperCase( ) == (ImqString)"TCP" ) {
          pchannel -> setTransportType( MQXPT_TCP );
        }

        // Establish the connection name.
        if ( strParse.cutOut( strToken ) ) {
          pchannel -> setConnectionName( strToken );
        }
      }
    }

    mgr.setChannelReference( pchannel );
  }

  // Connect to queue manager
  if ( ! mgr.connect( ) ) {

    /* stop if it failed     */
    printf( "ImqQueueManager::connect failed with reason code %ld\n",
            (long)mgr.reasonCode( ) );
    exit( (int)mgr.reasonCode( ) );
  }

  // Associate queue with queue manager.
  queue.setConnectionReference( mgr );

  // Open the named message queue for input; exclusive or shared
  // use of the queue is controlled by the queue definition here
  queue.setOpenOptions(
                   MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF /* open queue for input      */
                 + MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                             );        /* but not if MQM stopping   */
  queue.open( );

  /* report reason, if any; stop if failed      */
  if ( queue.reasonCode( ) ) {
    printf( "ImqQueue::open ended with reason code %ld\n",
            (long)queue.reasonCode( ) );
  }

  if ( queue.completionCode( ) == MQCC_FAILED ) {
    printf( "unable to open queue for input\n" );
  }

  // Get messages from the message queue
  // Loop until there is a failure
  msg.useEmptyBuffer( buffer, sizeof( buffer ) - 1 );
                                 /* buffer size available for GET   */
  gmo.setOptions( MQGMO_WAIT |   /* wait for new messages           */
                  MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING );
  gmo.setWaitInterval( 15000 );  /* 15 second limit for waiting     */

  while ( queue.completionCode( ) != MQCC_FAILED ) {

    // In order to read the messages in sequence, MsgId and
    // CorrelID must have the default value.  MQGET sets them
    // to the values in for message it returns, so re-initialise
    // them before every call
    msg.setMessageId( );
    msg.setCorrelationId( );

    if ( queue.get( msg, gmo ) ) {

      // Display each message received
      if ( msg.formatIs( MQFMT_STRING ) ) {

        buffer[ msg.dataLength( ) ] = 0 ;  /* add terminator          */
        printf( "message <%s>\n", msg.bufferPointer( ) );

      } else {
        printf( "Non-text message\n" );
      }

    } else {

      /* report reason, if any     */
      if ( queue.reasonCode( ) == MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE ) {
                                /* special report for normal end    */
        printf( "no more messages\n" );
      } else {
                                /* general report for other reasons */
        printf( "ImqQueue::get ended with reason code %ld\n",
                (long)queue.reasonCode( ) );

        /*   treat truncated message as a failure for this sample   */
        if ( queue.reasonCode( ) == MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED ) {
          break ;
        }
      }
    }

  }

  // Close the source queue (if it was opened)
  if ( ! queue.close( ) ) {

    /* report reason, if any     */
    printf( "ImqQueue::close failed with reason code %ld\n",
            (long)queue.reasonCode( ) );
  }

  // Disconnect from MQM if not already connected (the
  // ImqQueueManager object handles this situation automatically)
  if ( ! mgr.disconnect( ) ) {

    /* report reason, if any     */
    printf( "ImqQueueManager::disconnect failed with reason code %ld\n",
            (long)mgr.reasonCode( ) );
  }

  // Tidy up the channel object if allocated.
  if ( pchannel ) {
    mgr.setChannelReference( );
    delete pchannel ;
  }

  printf( "Sample IMQSGET end\n" );
  return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I dont want to use languages like java and c++. Do you think I can use shell/perl/python?

Comment: As far as I know there is no API for shell/perl/python. You can use command line tools that are included in WMQ Client like amqsgetc/amqsputc and others.

Answer (score 0):

IBM offers MQ clients for the following languages:

C, C++, .NET, Java

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere MQ provides support for the following programming procedural languages:
C
Visual Basic (Windows systems only)
COBOL
Assembler language (WebSphere MQ for z/OS® only)
RPG (WebSphere MQ for IBM® i only)
PL/I (WebSphere MQ for z/OS only)

These languages use the message queue interface (MQI) to access message queueing services.

WebSphere MQ provides support for:
.NET
ActiveX
C++
Java
JMS

These languages use the WebSphere MQ Object Model, which provides classes that provide the same functionality as WebSphere MQ calls and structure.

[Fuente](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/zd00060_.htm)